# Float Right on Last List Item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am wondering if you are able to float text to the right of the last list item in an ng-repeat.

What I want:

```
item 1           
item 2          
item 3          Only on last item
```

Code:

```
$scope.lists = {
  item1:  "item 1",
  item2: "item 2",
  item3: "item 3"
}

<li ng-repeat="list in lists">{{list}}<a style="float:right;">Only on last list item</a></li>
```

This only outputs as:

```
item 1          Only on last item
item 2          Only on last item
item 3          Only on last item
```

Here is a plunker of what I am trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/9i6lO3e60bwngnzECePF

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is about to show a block only on last item, as David made. If you need to float left on last item, you could use a css selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="list in lists">
{{list}}
<a ng-if="$last" style="float:right;">Only on last list item</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Within you ng-repeat, you can use $last to figure out if you're on the last item. See [angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!) for more info.

```
<li ng-repeat="list in lists">
    {{list}}
    <a ng-show="$last" style="float:right;">Only on last list item</a>
</li>
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/ADukg/7070/).